# Can I write an ipython script that quits ipython?

Tags: ipython

I would like a script that does something like:

```
x = 1
x += 1
exit
```

when I just type these in sequentially to ipython.

If I try just putting these in script.py and doing %run script.py, it doesn't work (neither does %run -i):

```
In [1]: %run test.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/david/nice_pngs/test.py in <module>()
      1 x = 1
      2 x += 1
----> 3 exit

NameError: name 'exit' is not defined

In [2]: %run -i test.py

In [3]:
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? How about pasting the actual script and output?

Comment: `sys.exit()` is the general Python equivalent. But I think you'll find that IPython catches that, so there isn't an easy way to exit from a script. Why do you want to do this? Does it make sense in your case to do `ipython test.py`, which will run the script and then exit automatically?

Comment: Thomas - yeah that is a better way, thanks.  I have gotten so used to running things interactively...